# change multiple shell commands into one in groovy

Tags: shell, groovy, jenkins-pipeline

Really new to groovy,I have very simple groovy code which run absolutely fine:

```
      sh """
          git checkout deploy
          git pull
          git branch
      """
      PREVIOS_VERSION = sh ( script: 'cat ' + VERSION_FILE + ' | grep current_version | awk -F\'[" "]\' \'{print $3}\'', returnStdout: true).trim()
      echo PREVIOS_VERSION
      sh "bumpversion ${SEMANTIC_VERSION_COMPONENT} --config-file ${VERSION_FILE} --verbose"
      NEW_VERSION = sh ( script: 'cat ' + VERSION_FILE + ' | grep current_version | awk -F\'[" "]\' \'{print $3}\'', returnStdout: true).trim()
      echo NEW_VERSION
      sh """
          git checkout ${GIT_BRANCH}
          git branch
      """
```

When I combine this code into one `sh` command like this:

```
      sh """
          git checkout deploy
          git pull
          git branch
          PREVIOS_VERSION = ( script: 'cat ' + VERSION_FILE + ' | grep current_version | awk -F\'[" "]\' \'{print $3}\'', returnStdout: true).trim()
          echo PREVIOS_VERSION
          bumpversion \${SEMANTIC_VERSION_COMPONENT} --config-file \${VERSION_FILE} --verbose
          NEW_VERSION = ( script: 'cat ' + VERSION_FILE + ' | grep current_version | awk -F\'[" "]\' \'{print $3}\'', returnStdout: true).trim()
          echo NEW_VERSION
          git checkout ${GIT_BRANCH}
          git branch
      """
```

Then I am getting this error:

```
WorkflowScript: 58: illegal string body character after dollar sign;
   solution: either escape a literal dollar sign "\$5" or bracket the value expression "${5}" @ line 58, column 7.
         sh """
```

Even I try to use the `\` character but still no luck. Can somebody tell me how I can achieve the end result.

Comment: You can't let interpret the `groovy` parts of the script with `bash`. It is like wanting from ruby interpret the `perl` script... :) Therefore it is split into 2 separate `sh` parts, with not-(pure)-shell parts in the middle.

Answer (score -1):

you need to add \n at the end of each line:

sh "git checkout deploy\n " +
   "git pull\n" +
   "git branch\n"

sorry for my  mistake , I just understood the question.

you can't do it in the way you wanted.
when you use the line :
PREVIOS_VERSION = sh ( script: 'cat ' + VERSION_FILE + ' | grep current_version | awk -F\'[" "]\' \'{print $3}\'', returnStdout: true).trim()

it is a groovy syntax calling a shell command.
you can't insert it in the shell since shell will not understand the syntax

Comment: I think this is not related to the error. I want single sh command for all the task, which give me above mentioned error